# Problem with virsh / cannot connect to qemu

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt, virsh

I am trying to setup KVM, but when running `$ sudo virsh net-define br10.xml` I get this:

`error: failed to connect to the hypervisor`

`error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory`

And when jumping into virt-manager GUI a get this dialog `Unable to connect to libvirt qemu:///system.`

I checked if I am in both kvm and libvirt groups and that seems okay.
I also checked if the libvrt-sock file is created when running `$ sudo systemctl start libvirtd.service` but there is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

So it showed up that privilges for my files wasn't set correctly. Now everything works